# iOS Provisioning Profile: Current Distribution Certificate

Tags: iphone, ios, provisioning-profile

Within the Apple Developer iOS Provisioning Profile, I am getting the message: "Your current distribution certificate is about to expire. Please request a new one."  Now my only options that I see are to request a new certificate, revoke the certificate, or download the current certificate.  Currently I have an app that we distribute adhoc (send the files to the field team and have them put them on phone via iTunes sync).  I've called Apple to see if there is a way to just renew my current certificate or if I have to create a new one and resend out the app to have the field team re-install the app.  I've gotten mixed answers from Apple saying that a renew button will appear once it expires but I also got an answer saying I need to request a new certificate.  Which one is it?  If I request a new certificate do I have to have the field team re-install the app afterwards?

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1):

Once your distribution certificate is over, you need to install the renewed license. You will find a renew option on your Provisional Profile Page of your Profile.
You need not request for new license. 
Also, once you have downloaded the renewed license you have to debug your code and send the team with the new application. It is hence necessary to watch out for expired licenses.
A good practise : if the license less than 10 days , renew it and debug and distribute.
Thats what I did !! Hope it helps.

--- Also please, accept the answers you think is correct. It will help others to know if their answers are correct or no.

Comment: Well, everyone keeps saying that there is a renew option but I do not have this option.  I've searched extensively for it but it is not there.  Any other thoughts?

Comment: You should have an option of renew button with invalid status. but if you cant find it in your provisioning profile I guess you may have to create a new one or ask apple to renew it for you.

Comment: After contacting Apple again they said to just create a new distribution certificate and upload it.  This time they said that the renew button will not be there - that is actually only for the provisioning profile.  Thx for the help.